# YouTube Upload Video ChannelID Parameter - Error

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the Python library and here is the code to authorize.

```py
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=8081)
```

Uploading part is

```py
youtube.videos().insert(
    onBehalfOfContentOwner="#####myuserid#####",
    onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel="#####mychannelid#####",
```

Initially I had created first first channel (say Channel A, the primary user channel), after sometimes, I had created one more channel (Say Channel B, Brand channel) under the same user account.

I did not specify the Channel id. The upload is successful and all is well. The video uploaded to Channel A. The problem is, I have one more channnel in the same user account, thus I have to specify the channel id. I could not find how to send the channel id.

I am not "YouTube content partners". I pass the channId to the onBehalfOfContentOwner but it fails. Please advise how to upload my own secondary channel. Here is the error I am receiving now.

```
googleapiclient.errors.ResumableUploadError: <HttpError 403 when requesting None returned "The authenticated user cannot act on behalf of the specified Google account.". Details: "[{'message': 'The authenticated user cannot act on behalf of the specified Google account.', 'domain': 'youtube.common', 'reason': 'accountDelegationForbidden'}]">
```